# How to get previous row value in DAX power bi

Tags: powerbi

```
family  month  qty  prev_qty

A        M07   5     5
A        M08   6     5
A        M09   7     6
B        M07   10    10
B        M08   11    10
B        M09   12    11
```

Previous qty is the column i want to populate in my dashboard. I used dax like earlier and also created index but its not helping. Any DAX function for this table to find the previous row value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad question. It seems what you are actually looking for is this:

**For each family sort the table by month, and either take the quantity from the preceeding month or the same month if there is no predecessor.**

This can be achieved using three calulated columns:

```
Current Row = RANKX( ALL('Table'), 'Table'[month], , ASC, Dense)
```

```
Previous Row = 
VAR CurrentRow = 'Table'[Current Row]
VAR PreviousRow = CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Current Row]), 
    ALL('Table'),
    'Table'[family] = EARLIER('Table'[family]),
    'Table'[month] < EARLIER('Table'[month])
)
RETURN IF( PreviousRow <> BLANK(), PreviousRow, CurrentRow )
```

```
Previous Quantity = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[qty]), 
    ALL('Table'), 
    'Table'[family] = EARLIER('Table'[family]), 
    'Table'[Current Row] = EARLIER('Table'[Previous Row])
)
```

[image]

Please accept the answer if this is what you're looking for and reward voluntary help.

Comment: Hi @Peter, this seems to be rather a (very good) question edit... and what do you replace Calculate(...) by ?

Comment: Thanks Peter for correcting my question. I tried with the solution. It works and i am struggling with the parameters for Calculate function. I tried with : CALCULATE ( sum(qty), FILTER ( table, table[Current Row]>= Table[Previous Row] ) ) ...but It doesnt work. Any Input here please? ( Qty is measure here in my case , hence sum(quantity) is throwing error.

Comment: There are no words for this. This is such a useful example. Thanks a million. Many other problems can be tackled with tiny variations on this bit of code.